# Finding line-wraps

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, text

Supposing I have some random block of text in a single line. Like so

`Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.`

But for whatever reason (width settings on the containing element, use of text-zoom etc.), on the viewer's screen it displays as two or more lines.

`Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,`

`consectetur adipiscing elit.`

or

`Lorem ipsum dolor sit`

`amet, consectetur`

`adipiscing elit.`

Is there any way to find out via javascript where those line-wraps happen?

`$('p').text()` and `$('p').html()` return `Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.` regardless of how the text is displayed.

Comment: If $('p').html() is returning that, then it is not line breaks. It could be the width on the 'p' element itself or one of its containers. Why don't you provide the context of the problem as well?

Comment: With HTML, JavaScript, jQuery or CSS, it's not possible. You could write a java applet or embed flash, but that seems to be too difficult. Why do you need it?

Comment: @Floyd Pink: That's what I meant. There aren't literal "\n"s in the code, the text is being displayed over multiple lines because of the <p>'s width. The question is, can I find out the contents of each line of the final display text?

Comment: @elektronikLexikon: Long story. Basically, I'm putting together a little web app to let some people generate some oddly specific documents, and I figured it would be easier to pull out the on-screen text layout rather than do typesetting myself at the generation step.

Comment: It is possible via javascript, as you could measure widths with alternative inline elements and check if they are the same - however this is extremely tedious. Sounds to me like your goal is ambiguous and you should rethink what you are trying to accomplish - perhaps use word-wrap is css or the like.

Comment: @balupton: AFAIK, word-wrap would just make sure that the text respects the paragraph boundaries. That really doesn't help in this case; the contained text is user-entered, and the point of the excercise is to figure out how it wraps on their screen so that they don't complain that the generated PS/PDF file has different word-wrapping. Like I said in the comment above, the other option is typesetting it at document generation, but if there's a way to just grab the wrapping from the front end, I'm not opposed to it.

Comment: @Inaimathi. Ahhh. Added a answer then :-)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here's what I ended up using (feel free to critique and copy for your own nefarious purposes).

First off, when the edit comes in from the user, it's broken up with `$(editableElement).lineText(userInput)`.

```
jQuery.fn.lineText = function (userInput) {
   var a = userInput.replace(/\n/g, " \n<br/> ").split(" ");
   $.each(a, function(i, val) { 
      if(!val.match(/\n/) && val!="") a[i] = '<span class="word-measure">' + val + '</span>';
   });
   $(this).html(a.join(" "));
};
```

The newline replacement happens because the editing textbox is populated with `$(editableElement).text()`, which ignores `<br/>` tags, but they will still change the height of the following line in the display for typesetting purposes. This was not part of the initial objective, just fairly low-hanging fruit.

When I need to pull out formatted text, I call `$(editableElement).getLines()`, where

```
jQuery.fn.getLines = function (){
   var count = $(this).children(".word-measure").length;
   var lineAcc = [$(this).children(".word-measure:eq(0)").text()];
   var textAcc = [];
   for(var i=1; i<count; i++){
      var prevY = $(this).children(".word-measure:eq("+(i-1)+")").offset().top;
      if($(this).children(".word-measure:eq("+i+")").offset().top==prevY){
         lineAcc.push($(this).children(".word-measure:eq("+i+")").text());
   } else {
     textAcc.push({text: lineAcc.join(" "), top: prevY});
     lineAcc = [$(this).children(".word-measure:eq("+i+")").text()];
   }
   }
   textAcc.push({text: lineAcc.join(" "), top: $(this).children(".word-measure:last").offset().top});
   return textAcc;
};
```

The end result is a list of hashes, each one containing the content and vertical offset of a single line of text.

```
[{"text":"Some dummy set to","top":363},
 {"text":"demonstrate...","top":382},
 {"text":"The output of this","top":420},
 {"text":"wrap-detector.","top":439}]
```

If I just want unformatted text, `$(editableElement).text()` still returns

```
"Some dummy set to demonstrate... The output of this wrap-detector."
```

Answer (score 29):

Well, if you want something that's ridiculously simple and probably too useless for you (it'll need major modification if you have any sort of HTML inside the paragraph), then have a look at this:

```
var para = $('p');

para.each(function(){
    var current = $(this);
    var text = current.text();
    var words = text.split(' ');

    current.text(words[0]);
    var height = current.height();

    for(var i = 1; i < words.length; i++){
        current.text(current.text() + ' ' + words[i]);

        if(current.height() > height){
            height = current.height();
            // (i-1) is the index of the word before the text wraps
            console.log(words[i-1]);
        }
    }
});
```

It's so ridiculously simple it might just work. What this does is to break up the text by spaces, then append the words back word by word, watching for any increase in the height of the element, which would indicate a line wrap.

Have a look at it here: http://www.jsfiddle.net/xRPYN/2/

Comment: The jsfiddle setup seems to stop at the first line. My knee-jerk reaction is that I can't use this because the user actually has control over the container width/height, but on reflection, I could just create a temp p somewhere off-screen with the same width, and no height specification (at which point I can clear current after each line to get the desired output of "a list of lines delimited at line-wraps"). I'll give it a try.

Comment: Awesome work... Here's the same thing without jQuery if anyone needs (only tested in chrome)
http://jsfiddle.net/tV29m/

Comment: Excellent!  I changed it into a function like:  function isTextWrapped(div)
{
    var wraps=0;
    var words = div.text().split(' ');
    div.text(words[0]);
    var height = div.height();
    for(var i = 1; i < words.length; i++){
        div.text(div.text() + ' ' + words[i]);
        if(div.height() > height){
            height = div.height();
            wraps++;
        }
    }
    return wraps;
}

Comment: I also confirmed it didn't mess up the text when having right to left text (arabic).  Though if you're worried you can have it store the original text and replace it at the end

Answer (score 13):

For a use case like pdf generation.

You can limit to characters per line, if a split occurs middle word, adjust appropriately.

To gain a more accurate characters per line you can use monospaced fonts then determine the width per character for each font allowed. Then divide the character width by the size of the allowed text line width, and you'll have the allowed characters per line for that font.

You could use non monospaced fonts, but then you'll have to measure each letter's width - ugh. A way you can automate the width guessing is having a span that has no margin or padding, add in each character for each font (and size) then measure the width of the span and use that.

I've done up the code:

```
/**
 * jQuery getFontSizeCharObject
 * @version 1.0.0
 * @date September 18, 2010
 * @since 1.0.0, September 18, 2010
 * @package jquery-sparkle {@link http://www.balupton/projects/jquery-sparkle}
 * @author Benjamin "balupton" Lupton {@link http://www.balupton.com}
 * @copyright (c) 2010 Benjamin Arthur Lupton {@link http://www.balupton.com}
 * @license Attribution-ShareAlike 2.5 Generic {@link http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.5/
 */
$.getFontSizeCharObject = function(fonts,sizes,chars){
    var fonts = fonts||['Arial','Times'],
        sizes = sizes||['12px','14px'],
        chars = chars||['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','y','x','z',
                        'A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','Y','X','Z',
                        '0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','-','=',
                        '!','@','#','$','%','^','&','*','(',')','_','+',
                        '[',']','{','}','\\','|',
                        ';',"'",':','"',
                        ',','.','/','<','>','?',' '],
        font_size_char = {},
        $body = $('body'),
        $span = $('<span style="padding:0;margin:0;letter-spacing:0:word-spacing:0"/>').appendTo($body);

    $.each(fonts, function(i,font){
        $span.css('font-family', font);
        font_size_char[font] = font_size_char[font]||{};
        $.each(sizes, function(i,size){
            $span.css('font-size',size);
            font_size_char[font][size] = font_size_char[font][size]||{};
            $.each(chars,function(i,char){
                if ( char === ' ' ) {
                    $span.html('&nbsp;');
                }
                else {
                    $span.text(char);
                }
                var width = $span.width()||0;
                font_size_char[font][size][char] = width;
            });
        });
    });

    $span.remove();

    return font_size_char;
};

/**
 * jQuery adjustedText Element Function
 * @version 1.0.0
 * @date September 18, 2010
 * @since 1.0.0, September 18, 2010
 * @package jquery-sparkle {@link http://www.balupton/projects/jquery-sparkle}
 * @author Benjamin "balupton" Lupton {@link http://www.balupton.com}
 * @copyright (c) 2010 Benjamin Arthur Lupton {@link http://www.balupton.com}
 * @license Attribution-ShareAlike 2.5 Generic {@link http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.5/
 */
$.fn.adjustedText = function(text,maxLineWidth){
    var $this = $(this),
        font_size_char = $.getFontSizeCharObject(),
        char_width = font_size_char['Times']['14px'],
        maxLineWidth = parseInt(maxLineWidth,10),
        newlinesAt = [],
        lineWidth = 0,
        lastSpace = null;

    text = text.replace(/\s+/g, ' ');

    $.each(text,function(i,char){
        var width = char_width[char]||0;
        lineWidth += width;
        if ( /^[\-\s]$/.test(char) ) {
            lastSpace = i;
        }
        //console.log(i,char,lineWidth,width);
        if ( lineWidth >= maxLineWidth ) {
            newlinesAt.push(lastSpace||i);
            lineWidth = width;
            lastSpace = null;
        }
    });

    $.each(newlinesAt,function(i,at){
        text = text.substring(0,at+i)+"\n"+text.substring(at+i);
    });

    text = text.replace(/\ ?\n\ ?/g, "\n");

    console.log(text,newlinesAt);

    $this.text(text);

    return $this;
};

$(function(){
    var $body = $('body'),
        $textarea = $('#mytext'),
        $btn = $('#mybtn'),
        $div = $('#mydiv');

    if ( $textarea.length === 0 && $div.length === 0 ) {
        $body.empty();

        $textarea = $('<textarea id="mytext"/>').val('(When spoken repeatedly, often three times in succession: blah blah blah!) Imitative of idle, meaningless talk; used sometimes in a slightly derogatory manner to mock or downplay another\'s words, or to show disinterest in a diatribe, rant, instructions, unsolicited advice, parenting, etc. Also used when recalling and retelling another\'s words, as a substitute for the portions of the speech deemed irrelevant.').appendTo($body);
        $div = $('<div id="mydiv"/>').appendTo($body);
        $btn = $('<button id="mybtn">Update Div</button>').click(function(){
            $div.adjustedText($textarea.val(),'300px');
        }).appendTo($body);

        $div.add($textarea).css({
            'width':'300px',
            'font-family': 'Times',
            'font-size': '14px'
        });
        $div.css({
            'width':'auto',
            'white-space':'pre',
            'text-align':'left'
        });
    }

});
```

Comment: This is way more work than I was expecting anyone to put in. +1. I think for my purposes, there's probably a simpler way though (since I really just need a list of lines delimited at the point they wrap, and I could probably get away with just breaking on words instead of letters, as long as I get the UI to do the same thing). I'll play around and post my code in a bit. Thanks for pointing me in this direction though.

Comment: Completely unrelated to functionality; you need to put .com in your `@package`

Answer (score 8):

The solutions above don't work once you have more complex structure like a link in a paragraph (e.g. you can have `<b><i><a href></a>` within a `<p>`).

So I made a javascript library to detect where lines wrap that works in those cases: http://github.com/xdamman/js-line-wrap-detector

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I have a situation where I need to wrap each line in a span. I do this so that I can add a padded highlight effect to a text block. Adding the background to a span tag that wraps the text will only pad the beginning and ending of the text block, each line must be wrapped individually.

This is what I came up with based on the suggestions above:

```
$.fn.highlghtWrap = function () {
    this.each( function () {
      var current = $( this );
      var text = current.text();
      var words = text.split( ' ' );
      var line = '';
      var lines = [];

      current.text( words[ 0 ] );
      var height = current.height();
      line = words[ 0 ];
      for ( var i = 1; i < words.length; i++ ) {
        current.text( current.text() + ' ' + words[ i ] );

        if ( current.height() > height ) {
          lines.push( line );
          line = words[ i ];
          height = current.height();
        } else {
          line = line + ' ' + words[ i ];
        }
      }
      lines.push( line );
      current.html( '' );
      $.each( lines, function ( v, a ) {
        current.html( current.html() + '<span>' + a +
          ' </span>' );
      } );
    } );
  }

  $( '.home-top_wrapper h2' ).highlghtWrap();
  $( '.home-top_wrapper p' ).highlghtWrap();
```

Answer (score -1):

A conceptually simple way that also works when there's internal markup and arbitrary fonts and styles, is to make a first pass that simply puts every word into its own element (maybe 'SPAN', or a custom name like 'w').

Then you can iterate using getBoundingClientRect() to find where the 'top' property changes:

```
function findBreaks() {
    var words = document.getElementsByTagName('w');
    var lastTop = 0;
    for (var i=0; i<words.length; i++) {
        var newTop = words[i].getBoundingClientRect().top;
        if (newTop == lastTop) continue;
        console.log("new line " + words[i].textContent + " at: " + newTop);
        lastTop = newTop;
    }
}
```

It sounds slow, but unless the documents are really big you won't notice.

Comment: This assumes that there are no styles that could apply to the new element that might throw things off.

Comment: @Sean Technically true, but (1) that's easy to check for, and (2) you can avoid it by wise choice of element type. For example, you can easily scan the applicable CSS, or  use a random made-up element name (which the usual HTML browsers are perfectly fine with). Try it.