# How do I make the text in the next line to be centered and not aligned to the left?

Tags: html, css

I have a div that has the following CSS:

```
 .div_stuff {
 width: 830px;
 margin: 20px auto;
 font-size:22px;
 }
```

How do I prevent the text that goes to the next line to not align left right under the text above but simply become centered on the next line?

Comment: I don't really get it. Some HTML code would help illustrate what your are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although I'm not sure if I understood what you want to achieve and I can't find a use case for this... Changing the alignment from the second line on would be possible by adding some span tags with javascript/jQuery ([**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/ctPyV/9/)):

```
$(function() {
    var box = $('.div_stuff');
    var text = box.text();

    var words = text.split(' ');
    box.text(words[0]);
    var height = box.height();
    var chars = 0;
    for(var i = 1; i < words.length; i++){
        box.text(box.text() + ' ' + words[i]);
        chars += words[i-1].length + 1;
        if(box.height() > height){
            height = box.height();      
            box.html('<span class="first-line">' + text.substring(0,chars) + '</span><span class="following-lines">' + text.substring(chars+1, text.length)+'</span>');
            break;
        }
    }
});
```

And set a different alignment to them:

```
span {
    display: block;
}

.first-line {
    text-align: left;
}

.following-lines {
    text-align: center;
}
```

I've used [that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3744583/983992) for determining auto line breaks.

Answer (score 2):

Add `text-align: center` to center the text inside. You are centering the div position only.

Comment: This would center all text, including the first line, which it seems is not the desired result.

Comment: Well, he didn't give a very good explanation. He just talks about "the next line" while giving us just a CSS class def.

Answer (score 0):

you can try css3 text justified

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_text-justify.asp

Comment: Can you expand on how exactly this would be used to do what the question is asking?  This also seems to currently only be supported by IE.

Comment: look you can center the div text by doing this only ...  http://jsfiddle.net/DNjLV/