# REGEX to select first two lines from a div

Tags: javascript, regex

Is there any way to select first two lines from text in a div.

```
Content in div:

/*------------------------
| some content goes here |
| inside div or any      |
| container in HTML. is  |
| it possible to select  |
| first two lines        |
| displaying in browser  |
----------------------- */

SelectedText = "some content goes here inside div or any"
```

Comment: The answer will be no.

Comment: As long as there are linebreaks or br tags in the content you can split the content into an array and then select the first two entries

Comment: Provide a definition for "line"

Comment: see [related question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3738490/2170192)

Answer (score 0):

```
var first_line = $("#divElement").text().split("\n")[1];
var second_line = $("#divElement").text().split("\n")[2];
```

[JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/CtX4B/)

Comment: Read comment above in Parfait's reply

Answer (score 0):

Hello you can check below code

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
function runTest(){
var str=document.getElementById("id1").value;
var arr = str.split(/[\n\r]/g);
alert(arr[0]+arr[1]);
}
</script>
<textarea id="id1">
some content goes here
inside div or any
container in HTML. is 
it possible to select
first two lines 
displaying in browser
</textarea>

<a href="#" onClick="runTest();">myLink</a>
```

Comment: Read comment above in Parfait's reply