# Add a border only to the bottom of wrapped text

Tags: border, inline, css, underline

I'm trying to achieve an underline on some wrapped text that fits to the width of the bottom row of text whilst only appearing underneath that bottom line. Figure 1 illustrates the desired effect

Figure 1

[image: how it should be]

Using this HTML:

```
<h2><span class="inline-block">optatur, volendit inum simolor</span></h2>
```

and setting the `span` to `display:inline;` I can get the underline to fit perfectly with the width of the text but it underlines all of the text.

*Or*, setting the `span` to `display:inline-block;` I can get the underline to only appear under the bottom line but it then fills the whole width of the parent.

See this JSfiddle for the above examples: http://jsfiddle.net/PWDV7/1/

Is there any way to achieve the result of figure 1?

Comment: @Pranavc u's shouldn't be used with html 4 and only with html5 if you are annotating something, otherwise you should use css to underline

Comment: Really interesting problem.

Comment: This is maddening. I can underline just the length of the last line, but not when it's centered. I've even considered resorting to JavaScript.

Comment: Hi Jordan! Glad you're getting on board with the head scratching! If it needs it, I'd be happy for a JavaScript solution...

Comment: I eventually managed to solve it with some JS! (See below.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a good leg up from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3738490/finding-line-wraps/3744583#3744583) to a questions about finding line wraps, I managed to come up with this solution (in short, it involves using JS to find where a line wrap has occurred and wraps a span around all the text that sits on the last line):

```
function underLineText () {
    $underlined_text.each(function(){
        var $this = $(this);
        var text = $this.text();
        var originalText = text;
        var breakWords = new Array();

        //split the words into individual strings 
        var words = text.split(' ');

        //find the height of the first word
        $this.text(words[0]);
        var height = $this.height();

        //if there is more than one word
        if (words.length > 1) {
            //loop through all the words
            for(var i = 1; i < words.length; i++){
                $this.text($this.text() + ' ' + words[i]);

                //check if the current word has a different height from the previous word
                //if this is true, we have witnessed a word wrap!
                if($this.height() > height){
                    height = $this.height();
                    //add the first word after the wrap to a predefined array
                    breakWords.push(words[i]);
                }

                //on the last iteration on the loop...
                if (i === words.length - 1) {
                    if (breakWords.length > 0) {
                        //select the last word of the breakWords array
                        //(this is to handle cases where there there are more than one line or word wraps)
                        var breakStartAt = breakWords[breakWords.length - 1];
                        //add a span before the last word
                        var withSpan = '<span>'+breakStartAt;
                        //replace the last occurrence of this word with the span wrapped version
                        //(this is to handle cases where there are more than one occurrences of the last word)
                        originalText = originalText.replaceLast(breakStartAt,withSpan);
                        //close the last line with a span
                        originalText += "</span>";

                    }
                }
            }
        }
        //if there are no word wraps, wrap the whole text in spans
        else {
            originalText = '<span>'+originalText+'</span>';
        }

        //replace the original text with the span-wrapped mod
        $(this).html(originalText);
    });
}
```

You can see it working here: http://jsfiddle.net/PWDV7/5/

Comment: Completely forgot about this question! This is pretty much where my thoughts were heading too; the closest I got was using a border on a positioned `after` pseudo-element, which would only work if the text is left-aligned. Good job!

Answer (score 0):

Change the code like so:

**HTML**

```
<h2>optatur, volendit <span>inum simolor</span></h2>
```

**CSS**

```
h2 {
    width:200px;
    text-align:center;
}
h2 span {
    border-bottom:3px solid black;
    width:100%;
}
```

All I changed was the position of the `<span>` to wrap the text that you want the border on.

**[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PWDV7/2/)**

Comment: I guess the OP doesn't want to make specific in the html what portion of text is going be underlined

Comment: instead of `border-bottom` u can use `text-decoration:underline;`

Comment: It depends how thick you want the border to be.

Comment: Thanks for your help Jamie, but yes, Danko's right; the text wil be created by people using a CMS and I can't rely on them putting in spans in the right places...