# How to match inline-block after element in firefox

Tags: css, firefox

In Chrome the second line is underlined. I'm looking to have this same effect but on Firefox. I know that if one was to use

```
display:-moz-inline-stack
```

prior to inline-block, it will fix the inline issues, however this does not solve the line stretching across. Any thoughts? This should be able to handle multiple lines, not just the one provided.

http://jsfiddle.net/VHdyf/

Comment: I opened your fiddle in Chrome 50 and FF 45 - no difference. Your "underline" is not overflowing the width of the paragraph.

Comment: I made a fiddle with a second very paragraph (multiple lines): http://jsfiddle.net/VHdyf/51/.  
Do you want the underlining effect on the bottom on the paragraph, but only stretching as long as it's last line?
As shown here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15180827/advanced-css-challenge-underline-only-the-final-line-of-text-with-css (where your fiddle is from), that's not possible to accomplish.

Comment: The only thing, that may be possile, is using JS as shown here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20500237/add-a-border-only-to-the-bottom-of-wrapped-text

Comment: The closest thing with pure CSS is like this: http://jsfiddle.net/VHdyf/52/. But it's pretty "hacky".

Comment: @Seika85 thanks for the responses - yes, your fiddle definitely helps exaggerate this issue. I was hoping to stay in the realm of css, if possible. Thinking this may be a lost cause.