# Making all lines in a paragraph the same width regardless character count

Tags: jquery, css, user-interface, font-size

I am making a GUI for a clients website. Its a T Shirt website where they want a really simple designer with limited options.

This is fine, however one of the options they have requested is to easily make all lines the same width. This results in larger font for some lines.

The provided text is in one text field, I then use:

```
word-wrap: break-word;
```

to break that line to fill the container.

This would end up as the example on the right, instead of the left.

[image]

Would this be possible with CSS prefered but JS can be used too.

Comment: css wouldn't do it, you'd need js to calculate different font sizes for each word so it'd fit into the same horizontal width.

Comment: Thought so, worth seeing if there was a solution for CSS out there. Ill keep digging.

Comment: I'm thinking 1. Treat each line separately 2. Put each line in a container and the whole thing in a container 3. Proportion so that as a line container needs to get wider to fill the main container, the height also grows. This will definitely need some javascript, but will be mostly done with css.

Comment: Working on a solution.  Will it always be one word per line?

Comment: @VCode sadly not, its however the word-wrap breaks up the words. Pretty poor example images from me so I apologise.

Comment: Found this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3744583/2921557 which could do the trick.

Comment: Are you trying to make it so you can click and edit the text in that box? Or are you just trying to display the text?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind breaking each line into it's own container (`span` or any other...) you can do it with javascript. The key is `font-size` CSS attribute.

You need to calculate the widest line (use `offsetWidth` to get each line's width), then calculate for each line how much spare width it leaves, divide that by the length of text in the line multiply by your base font size and set the attribute.

Here's a working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/n1wj2vmp/2/).

Answer (score 1):

The [BigText jQuery plugin](https://github.com/zachleat/BigText) is capable of doing exactly what you wish to do.

```js
$('#bigtext').bigtext();
```

```css
#bigtext{
  width:300px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://zachleat.github.io/BigText/dist/bigtext.js"></script>
<div id="bigtext">
  <span>SOME</span>
  <span>TOTALLY</span>
  <span>HIPSTER</span>
  <span>QUOTE</span>
  <span>ABOUT</span>
  <span>LIFE</span>
</div>
```

Comment: This doesn't work.  He said the text was in one field.

Comment: @RobertMcKee Honestly, the core issue is the dynamic font sizing. Splitting up a text in a different way is in comparison a no brainer. StackOverflow isn't a code writing service, it's a problem solving community.

Comment: Really if you are going to use a javascript, then breaking the line into multiple elements is about as difficult as increasing font size until it wraps.  Neither is terribly difficult to do.

Comment: @RobertMcKee Except for the part where there are no edge cases with splitting words into `<span>`'s, whilst figuring out the best way to make a text fit a certain space is a lot harder. The library doesn't only calculate font size, it also accounts for word-spacing and letter-spacing. None of the other on the spot answers here account for that.

Answer (score 1):

You can increase the font size until the text gets wider than the parent. Have a look at this recursive function (using jQuery):

```
function findLargestFontSize($line){
    var oldSize = parseInt($line.css('font-size'));
    //set new size
    $line.css('font-size', oldSize + 1 + 'px');
    // check if hit the edges
    if( $line.width() > $line.parent().width() ){
        $line.css('font-size', oldSize + 'px');
        return(oldSize);
    } else {
        findLargestFontSize($line);
    }
}
```

And [a fiddle with an example](https://jsfiddle.net/0o47nyfc/3/).

---

**EDIT**

I found Amit's answer to be a lot more elegant than this, so I merged with my solution. [Here is another fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0o47nyfc/6/)

```
var $target = $('#target');
var words = $target.text().split(' ');

// split words into lines
$target.empty();  
for(var i = 0; i < words.length; i++){
    var $newLine = $('<span style="display: table;">' + words[i] + '</span>');
    $target.append($newLine);
    if($newLine.width() < $target.width()) {
        $newLine.css('font-size', parseInt( $newLine.css('font-size'))  * ( $target.width() / $newLine.width()) + 'px');
    }
};
```