# Textarea - get each line, find line breaks

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, textarea

I want to get each line in a textarea. The textarea is small and wraps words according to width constraints. So I tried:

```
// Sample text: I want to find(line wrapped) all lines here

$("#textarea1").val().split(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm).length
// 1, not the right length, should be 2

$("#textarea1").val().split(/\r?\n/g).length
// 1

$("#textarea1").val().split("\n").length
// 1

$("#textarea1").val().split("\r").length
// 1
```

I also tried`wrap="hard"` and `white-space: pre-wrap` individually and together. 
 **Nothing seems to find line-breaks**!! Need help, thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure this is even possible. Not without traversing the shadow DOM (which not every browser has). This is because the wrapping is due to CSS and is not saved in the value of the textarea.

Comment: This question seems to be extremely relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3738490/finding-line-wraps

Comment: Hmm, it is pretty relevant, almost does the work!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the way I did it was:

- Clone the `textarea in question - $("#text")` into a transparent textarea. Use transparent font.
- Change id value of clone to, say, `$("#newtext")` and append it to DOM.
- On every keyup, we take the value of $("#text") before `this character's keyup`. Put that value into `$("#newtext")` and check if `$("#newtext").get(0).scrollHeight() > $("#newtext").height()`. If true => `this` character caused a line break.
- Increase rows of `$("#newtext")` in a loop until 
  `$("#newtext").get(0).scrollHeight() === $("#newtext").height()`
- Take text before `this` character, add a `\n`, add `this` character to `$("#newtext").val()`
- Apply `$("#newtext").val()` to `$("#text").val()`.
- Remove `$("#newtext")` from DOM.
- Repeat all of above steps on every keyup event

Above answer works on similar lines as -  [stackoverflow.com/questions/3738490/finding-line-wraps – evolutionxbox yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3738490/finding-line-wraps%20%E2%80%93%20evolutionxbox%20yesterday)

So, basically we convert line breaks into newlines which can be found by using `$("#text").val().split("\n")`. 
 
(Note - If we don't append transparent textarea to the DOM, its `scrollHeight()` will be `undefined`)

Answer (score 0):

I think it's just like you said: the textarea wraps words according to width constraints — which means are no line breaks for you to find. The line breaks you're looking for are characters, and those characters have not been inserted into your text.

Comment: The problem with detecting character widths is that is dependent on font size as well as font type. For example, in Tahoma, width of l (small L) is way less than G, I would guess that the difference is less for Times New Roman. That makes it complicated.