# Correct symbol for check hyphen

Tags: javascript, html

I use the same method to get lines from div
[Finding line-wraps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3738490/finding-line-wraps)

But....
*Method does not take text with hyphens.*

What I do...

I split word with `hyphens by inter-na-tional (U+00AD)` to 
`['inter','na','tional']` and check each piece for next line with simple `dash(minus)."-" U+002D`

But...Seems like it is not correct, because it has some different as you can 
see in screenshot: http://prnt.sc/d5h3t7

Which symbol shell I use to be able to check it correct?

Comment: You should split on both dash and hyphens. But please show the code that have the problem, as we could understand what you mean with *split*.

Comment: I just use simple split
item.word.split(/\u00AD|&shy;/);

But i can not understand. Is there  visual different bitween U+00AD and U+002D. I wiil try to make example for understanding...

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/w4dxb7f3/ I made new test, and i see that here http://prnt.sc/d5iwau .There is different... after space U+002D  more than U+00AD

Comment: You should not look at the visual differences, just the text you're elaborating, so you should look there what it contains. For example *&shy;* only works if the text contains this sequence, but if the text contains the character *-* it wont work.